# using GreaterThan's option propertyPath with embedded objects

Tags: php, symfony, constraints

I'm trying to use the comparison constraint GreaterThan with propertyPath option with an embedded object, and after submitting the form i get this error

```
PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path "ad.dateDebut" at property "dateDebut".
```

Booking.php

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ad", inversedBy="bookings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ad;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\Date(message="Attention la date de debut doit être au bon format")
     * @Assert\GreaterThan("tomorrow", message="La date de debut doit être ulterieure à la date d'aujourd'hui")
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(propertyPath="ad.dateDebut", message="La date de debut doit être ulterieure à la date de debut de disponibilité de l'annonce")
     * @Assert\LessThan(propertyPath="ad.dateFin", message="La date de debut doit être antérieure à la date de fin de disponibilité de l'annonce")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\Date(message="Attention la date de remise doit être au bon format")
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(propertyPath="startDate", message="La date de remise doit être plus éloignée de la date d'arrivée")
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(propertyPath="ad.dateDebut", message="La date de remise doit être ulterieure à la date de debut de disponibilité de l'annonce")
     * @Assert\LessThan(propertyPath="ad.dateFin", message="La date de remise doit être antérieure à la date de fin de disponibilité de l'annonce")
     */
    private $endDate;
```

Ad.php

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateDebut;
```

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your function of controller ? And Dump of data before persist

Comment: just as i went to my controller, i solved the issue, it turns out i was passing the $booking object to the form, without setting an ad for it, sorry for posting that question.

Comment: No problem, no need to be sorry :) just resolved